# How to use the package react-native-dotenv with different env files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, environment-variables

I have a react native web app with expo. And I have different env files. For dev and prod.

And I installed the package react-native-dotenv.

So I have a .env file:

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false 
REACT_APP_NAME=ddev
API_URL=http://127.0.0.1
```

and a .env.production file:

```
REACT_APP_ENV=PRODUCTION
API_URL=https://dierenwelzijndocker.azurewebsites.net
```

And I have configured the babel.config.js file:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
        plugins: [
            "babel-plugin-styled-components-react-native-web",
            [
                "module:react-native-dotenv",
                {
                    envName: "APP_ENV",
                    moduleName: "@env",
                    path: ".env",
                    blocklist: null,
                    allowlist: null,
                    safe: false,
                    allowUndefined: false,
                    verbose: false,
                },
            ],
        ],
    };
};
```

And I use the @env file in this method:

```
export const loginRequest = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/user/token/`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password,
            }),
        });

        const data = await response.json();

        if (response.ok) {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("Token", data.token);
            //
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new Error(data.token);
        }
    } catch (error) {       
        error, "email en of wachtwoord is niet goed ingevuld";
    }
};
```

And this works for local development.

But now I want to use the production env file. So I can build a package web-build that I can punt on the remote server.

So how to use the other env file: The production env file where the url is for the production environment?

what I have to change?

Question: how to use the production env file for production?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but not with expo, just cli. Why are you declaring module dotenv inside babel-plugin-styled-components-react-native-web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this Expo doc page](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/metro/), files are loaded according to standard .env rules.  Those rules [are listed here](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/blob/c6e583a/README.md#can-i-use-dotenv-in-production).

Comment: @Greg.But how to use the other .env file? Because that is the whole idea of .env files, isnt? That you don't have to edit the api url for dev and prodcution. Otherwise you have to change every time all the api url's

Comment: Not once in Production.  A production build is a static build.  There is no ".env" once you do a build and deploy that.  At build time the appropriate .env gets consumed and the values replace the environment variables in your code.  In a build, you have the hard-coded values not the "environment variable look up".  There are no env vars in a production web or RN system.  And if you are using Expo, I don't think you need to install react-native-dotenv on your own?  I think it is part of the Expo ecosystem?

Comment: But how to switch then from files. I have now as api url: localhost. But if I go to production. I have api url: http:www.producion.com... so how to use then the other api url?

Comment: You'd have to do different builds, and deploy each one independently.  Otherwise, use a mechanism that remains dynamic in production....and that would NOT be dotenv